# json stringify 2 arrays needed to place them in variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an ajax response in json format. Then in my javascript (ajax response success) i have the two arrays stringify. Now I need to place data in one curly bracket to 2 variables and then other curly bracket in another 2 variables.

Here's the code

```
var results = JSON.stringify(result).substr(1,JSON.stringify(result).length-2);
```

Here's the ajax(.js file)(part of it now whole code)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/default_q.php",
  dataType: "json", 
  type: 'POST',
  data: {dtime: n},

  success: function(result) {
    var results = JSON.parse(result);
    var mtime = results.microtime;
    var srp = results.srp;

    alert(mtime);
    alert(srp);
```

Here's the php

```
$sql = "SELECT microtime,srp FROM loading WHERE submit_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' AND microtime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)) and 1480573758";
$res   = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $content[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($content);
```

[image]

Ok. I want the microtime which is highligthed in yellow be stored in variable a so if I alert the a it will look like the photo below although not exactly the same. And same as the srp.

[image]

How will I achieve that. PLease help/.

Comment: You want JSON.parse, not stringify.. Stringify is to make an object into a JSON string.  JSON.parse is to make a JSON string into an object.

Comment: Whenever I used JSON.parse it has the error like this Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: That's because JQuery ajax has done the JSON.parse for you.  So just do `results[0].microtime`.   Notice the `[0]`, looking at your example it appears the JSON is an array.

Comment: `results[0].microtime` will work if I only have 1 microtime. number of microtime might range from 0 to many. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I'm assuming you know how to traverse an array, this would be a different question if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your `JSON` ajax response and traverse it as a `object` rather than using `substr` to break the string.

```
var results = JSON.parse(result);
var mtime = results[0].microtime;
var srp = results[0].srp;
```

**Update**

Since you have already used `dataType: "json"` jQuery has already parsed JSON string into object. You don't have to explicitly parse JSON again. Here is the updated code:

```
var mtime = results[0].microtime;
var srp = results[0].srp;
```

You can loop through the array to traverse through all values.

Comment: Whenever I used JSON.parse it has the error like this **Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**

Comment: Please post your complete JSON response.

Comment: May I ask how. Sorry I'm not really into javascript.

Comment: I did this. `var arrayLength = result.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            alert(result[i]);
            //Do something
        }`
i used result instead results which is stringify.
It alerted object object

Comment: Your are close.  Use this `alert(result[i].microtime);`

Comment: Wish I can vote your answer not only once. You really helped me alot. Back to the drawing board. I really need to study javascript real hard now.

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: Is this correct....`var arrayLength = results.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var a = result[i].microtime;
            var b = result[i].srp;
        }`
I kept getting an error **Cannot read property 'microtime' of undefined**

Comment: variable name is different. Use `results`instead of `result`

Comment: `var results = JSON.stringify(result).substr(1,JSON.stringify(result).length-2);;
        
        var arrayLength = results.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var a = results[i].microtime;
            var b = results[i].srp;
        }

        alert(a);`
Returned undefined Sir.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Sir.